# How to send google recaptcha from pc to phone

Tags: recaptcha

I'm working in python on the pc and flutter on smartphone. I wanted to run some code on pc, but as the websites I'm interacting with sometimes send me a google recaptcha, I am unable to continue on the pc, because I am not on it. What I wanted to do was to send let's say a link to my phone, I open the link and fill the recaptcha, letting the code on the pc continue doing the work. How can I do this? Is there any link I can grab from the recaptcha form so that sending it to the phone, I can fill the recaptcha on my phone and proceed the execution of the pc?

Comment: You mean, your python app serves as backend for flutter frontebd, and your trying to forward captcha from backend to client when captcha-protected site asks for it during some scraping? Please consider rewording the question, I had to reread it four times to figure this out...

Comment: I think you can forget the flutter. Let's say I'm working in python on the pc, and want to send a link to my phone in which upon opening it, the recaptcha appears on my phone and I fill the recaptcha. Then, the code on the pc can continue as if I filled the recaptcha on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are totally missing the purpose of a recaptcha.  It appears you are doing some sort of screen (web) scraping scenario.  The recaptcha is there specifically to prevent you from scraping and automation within the browser.  You would need some ridiculously complicated mechanism to carry on as you are trying to do.

If there's a recaptcha in the midst, you might need to rethink your strategy on automation.